Django One View for different models
There are several models in my Django project with one similar field - "comment".
I want to create an UpdateView for updating only this one field. I can do it by writing an UpdateView for each model. But I am wondering if can I write one UpdateView class for each of these models if the functionality of the class is the same, it is only the model name that needs to be changed.

To keep your code DRY, you could go with an approach like this:
# recommended option
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from myapp.models import Author, AnotherModel

class CommentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields = ["comment"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'model') or not self.model:
            raise AttributeError("CommentUpdateView requires 'model' attribute.")
        return self.model.objects.all()


# Then, for each model, you create a specific view:
class AuthorCommentUpdateView(CommentUpdateView):
    model = Author

class AnotherModelCommentUpdateView(CommentUpdateView):
    model = AnotherModel

Only having ONE UpdateView for all models that hold a comment field is a bad idea. Because the model has to be passed to the UpdateView as a parameter during runtime. The only way to pass something to the view is via the url. This gives the user full access to test for existing models and exposes your data. Since this is what you asked for - there you go:
# NOT recommended option
# views.py
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.apps import apps
from django.http import Http404

class DynamicCommentUpdateView(UpdateView):
    fields = ["comment"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        model_name = self.kwargs.get('model_name')
        if model_name:
            try:
                model = apps.get_model('myapp', model_name)
                if 'comment' not in [field.name for field in model._meta.fields]:
                    raise ValueError("Model does not have 'comment' field.")
                return model.objects.all()
            except (LookupError, ValueError):
                raise Http404("No model found with the given name that has a 'comment' field.")
        else:
            raise AttributeError("DynamicCommentUpdateView requires 'model_name' in URL kwargs.")

# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import DynamicCommentUpdateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:model_name>/<int:pk>/update/', DynamicCommentUpdateView.as_view(), name='dynamic-update'),
]

Above code determines from the string in the url what model is about to be updated. As said, bad idea.

Set an instance of models.Manager on the View during instantiation. When you eventually instantiate the View in the case of class based Views, you can use the as_view() method to override attributes set on the class for various instances of the class.
This example sets a queryset attribute on a View, UpdateView. It then overrides this attribute in as_view():
class UpdateView(View):
    queryset = None
    def put(self, request):
        self.queryset.all().update(comment="")
        return HttpResponse("All comments have been cleared.")
urlpatterns = [
    path("clear-all-model1-comments/", UpdateView.as_view(queryset=Model1.objects)),
    path("clear-all-model2-comments/", UpdateView.as_view(queryset=Model2.objects)),
    path("clear-all-model3-comments/", UpdateView.as_view(queryset=Model3.objects)),
]

You can set the model or queryset attribute as well instead of adding a custom manager attribute. Those should be present out of the box in the relevant class based views
